# redirect stdout & stderr to syslog

Tags: c, linux

In a program i want all the printfs to be written to syslog. I replace all printf to syslog so i thought of redirecting stdout and stderr to syslog. For that I tried the following code

```
int main()
{
    FILE *fl;
    fl = popen("logger","w");
    if(fl == NULL)
        return 1;
    fprintf(fl,"logger test new");//this goes to /var/log/messages
    int nf;
    nf = fileno(fl);
    dup2(nf,STDOUT_FILENO);
    dup2(nf,STDERR_FILENO);
    fprintf(stdout,"Wriiten in stdout\n");
    fprintf(stderr,"Wriiten in stderr\n");
    pclose(fl);
}
```

Issue is stderr goes to syslog and nothing is printed on the screen and program is hung.
Please suggest.

Comment: Are you limited to C or would you be willing to use C++ in a solution?

Comment: You need to close `stdout` and `stderr` before the `pclose()`

Comment: ...reason: `stderr` works because it is unbuffered. `stdout` is buffered and closing it flushes the buffer.

Comment: You say that "nothing is printed on the screen" as if it is a problem.  Do you want your errors to be written to the stderr of the caller (the terminal if invoked from a shell) and to the system log, or only to the system log?  Similarly, to you want stdout to be written twice?

Answer (score 4):

```
dup2(nf,STDOUT_FILENO);
dup2(nf,STDERR_FILENO);
fprintf(stdout,"Wriiten in stdout\n");
fprintf(stderr,"Wriiten in stderr\n");
fflush(stdout);
```

This should solve it.

`fflush()` will force the buffered data to be written from stdout.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to `fflush(stdout)` could be to disable the stdout buffering using :

```
setbuf (stdout,NULL);
```