# Redirect stdout/stderr using dup2, then resinstate later

Tags: c, linux, io-redirection, dup

**Background:** We have an embedded linux system running Busybox (limited resources), we have a process running which normally spits out lots of info on the console (via stdout / stderr) but we'd like to *temporarily* redirect it to syslog (using syslogd / logger) on command - WITHOUT restarting the process or rebooting.

Using the code found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14505079/redirect-stdout-stderr-to-syslog) works nicely, until we try to stop/close the logger fd at which point writes to stdout/stderr fail and everything breaks. Example below:

```
int main()
{

    // Got command to direct all output to syslog:

    FILE *fl;
    fl = popen("logger","w");
    if(fl == NULL)
        return 1;
    fprintf(fl,"logger test new"); // This goes to syslogd
    int nf;
    nf = fileno(fl);
    dup2(nf,STDOUT_FILENO);
    dup2(nf,STDERR_FILENO);
    fprintf(stdout,"Written in stdout\n");
    fprintf(stderr,"Written in stderr\n");

    // ...some time later when we've logged enough things:

    pclose(fl);
    fprintf(stdout,"This will fail\n");
    fprintf(stderr,"Catch fire and die\n");
}
```

So the question is, (how)can we restore the original state once we're done with the logging?

Having RTFM on `dup()` and `dup2()` I'm not clear on how exactly we can achieve this, if it's possible to "reopen" perhaps `freopen()` stdout/stderr, but as a last resort it would be acceptable to perhaps point `nf` to `/dev/null/` so things at least don't crash.

Comment: You must dup the initial file descriptors before your dup2, otherwise dup2 closes them and there is no way to recover them.

Comment: Something like:
`old_out=dup(STDOUT_FILENO);
old_err=dup(STDERR_FILENO);`
to take a copy, then when done:
`dup2(old_out,STDOUT_FILENO);
dup2(old_err,STDERR_FILENO);`
 yes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must dup the initial file descriptors before your dup2, otherwise dup2 closes them and there is no way to recover them.

```
int stdout_copy = dup(STDOUT_FILENO);
dup2(nf, STDOUT_FILENO);

/* do something with stdout */

dup2(stdout_copy, STDOUT_FILENO);
close(stdout_copy);
```

Throw in error handling, add `fflush` calls to ensure you don't leave data unwritten in stdlib buffers and you should be good.

Comment: Guess you answered my comment while I was typing it, thanks!

Comment: I was :). Of course it would be better if whatever is in the middle was able to accept a file descriptor to write onto, eliminating the need to redirect, but when working with third party code you sadly just have to make do.

Comment: Yeah, there's way too much code in the middle to replace all the print statements with something else.

Answer (score 0):

Linux man pages are clear that dup2 doesn't close the `oldfd`. Don't forget to also close `nf`.